# Raspberry Pi GPIO: Hardware Timing (e.g. Interrupts)

Tags: raspberry-pi3, interrupt, gpio

I've been trying to find any way to do hardware timing control on the Raspberry Pi but have been unable to find anything.

I need to be able to generate stable timing over the GPIO pins on the RasPi (e.g. to communicate with an FPGA at high-bandwidths) and need upwards of a 10-100MHz clock on the GPIO pins.

Everything I've seen so far uses delays to achieve timing, which is a really bad way of doing timing. For one, you don't get timing guarantees and get clock jitter; on top of this, I can't get a 10-100 MHz clock uwith `usleep`.

How do I get an interrupt or some other hardware-controlled timing for GPIO?